# The All python inbuilt function

Tags: python

```
if all(x not in phonebookcontent for x in [firstname, lastname, phone]) and phonebook_rule.match(imp):
```

This statement, how I can say "if one of [firstname, lastname, phone] is not in phonebookcontent then we can apply something" it's like the "or" statement instead of "all" that can be like "and"

Comment: Are you looking for [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=any#any)?

Comment: Or `not all(.. in ..)`…?

Comment: Yes it's any thanks

Comment: not all X == any not X

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if any(x not in phonebookcontent for x in [firstname, lastname, phone]) and phonebook_rule.match(imp):
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any